# Linux command on wake up from hibernate/suspend

Tags: linux, hibernate, linux-mint, suspend

I'm new to Linux and running Mint. I've seen a lot of documentation on creating commands that run when the os is started up from the computer being powered off. Is there a way to make similar commands to run when the os wakes up from hibernate or suspend? (For context, I'm running 'rfkill block bluetooth' on startup and would like to when my pc wakes up from hibernate as well).

Comment: you can think of adding script at cron job

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

place your commands in a script file and ensure you have sufficient owner/permissions to execute in  **/lib/systemd/system-sleep/** so once your OS suspends from sleep, its going to execute.

For more information
**man systemd-sleep**

https://askubuntu.com/questions/226278/run-script-on-wakeup